# How can I see modified files in a capistrano release?

Tags: git, capistrano

I'd like to check if someone modified my files (coworker -> hotfix or hacker -> hack) before releasing a new release.
Is it possible to see changed files via `git status` in a capistrano release?

```
$ ls -l
total 21692
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user www-data       55 Dec 14 14:31 current -> /path/to/my/releases/20161214132953
drwxr-xr-x 7 user www-data     4096 Dec 14 14:31 releases
drwxr-xr-x 7 user www-data     4096 Aug 18 14:05 repo
-rw-r--r-- 1 user www-data   121235 Dec 14 14:31 revisions.log
drwxr-xr-x 5 user www-data     4096 Dec  8  2014 shared
$ cd current
$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
$ cd ../repo
$ git status
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do it, although it is not obvious.

First, use `tail revisions.log` to find the Git commit SHA that was used for the release.

```
$ tail -n1 revisions.log
Branch master (at 66ba18ca4f689a7e9fdc9a45ba3c952785620157) deployed as release 20161214132953 by mbrictson
```

Next, go to the `repo` directory and use the `git archive` command to create a pristine snapshot of the repository that existed at that commit.

```
$ mkdir -p /tmp/pristine-release
$ git archive 66ba18ca4 | tar -x -f - -C /tmp/pristine-release
```

Now you can use `diff` to see the differences:

```
$ diff -r /tmp/pristine-release /path/to/releases/20161214132953
```

If you want to ignore files via `.gitignore` you can use the following command:

```
rsync \
  -vanc\
  --no-links \
  --no-group \
  --no-owner \
  --no-perms \
  --no-times \
  --delete \
  --filter="dir-merge,- .gitignore" \
  /path/to/current/ \
  /tmp/pristine-release \
  | head -n -3 \
  | tail -n +2 \
  | grep -v 'skipping non-regular file'
```

`--filter="dir-merge,- .gitignore"` reads and uses `gitignore`
`| head -n -3` removes rsync footer
`| tail -n +2` removes rsync header
`| grep -v 'skipping non-regular file'` removes skipped files from list